# Does Exchange 2003 have some limit on storing sent items on server?

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-2007, outlook-2003, outlook-anywhere

Problem:
I've Exchange 2003 on SBS 2003. I've a user which uses outlook at work, outlook at home (through HTTPS) and OWA occasionally from different places. Unfortunately some of the emails sent via outlook at home are not visible as sent (not appearing), and some are.

Question:
Is Exchange having some limit that lets say emails bigger then 5mb (or some other criteria) when sent are only stored locally in outlook but are not placed in sent items on server so if you check via HTTPS it's not there? If yes if that limit is changeable somewhere as it's something i would like to fix so all emails sent by users are stored within exchange so they can easily swap places they work at.

With regards,

MadBoy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such limit. You should find out if the user at home is sending through the Exchange server, or if they have multiple accounts configured in their Outlook and might be sending through one of the non-work accounts.

Comment: To my knowledge she has only one account which is exchange thru https (and i was the one setting it up on 2 laptops). And some other girl is using OWA and asked me the same question.

Comment: I should say, I'm not aware of any such limit out of the box - don't know off the top of my head if there's something that the Exchange admin can configure in this regard. And my suggested scenario obviously couldn't apply to anyone using OWA.